# How to passing message to client in passportjs

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Currently, I got the problem to get message from nodejs
[image]

In client (that separated from nodejs),

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').controller('RegisterCtrl', function ($scope, alert, $auth) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $auth.signup({
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
        })
            .then(function (res) {
                alert('success', 'Account Created!', 'Welcome, ' + res.data.user.email + '! Please email activate your account in the next several days.');
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                alert('warning', 'Unable to create account :(', err.message);
            });
    };
});
```

Although, On Nodejs passport I get the error "email already taken" but it can't pass this message into client, client just receive 401 (unauthorized).
I also install connect-flash and set

```
app.post('/auth/register', passport.authenticate('local-register', {
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}), function (req, res) {
    emailVerification.send(req.user.email, res, req);
    createSendToken(req.user, res);
});
```

but still no luck. How can I get this message? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flash message is set to `req` and not returned in HTTP response. If you were to render HTML on the server you could use it, but it does not work for AJAX.

Whilst I don't know why you are using authentication library for handling registrations, you could achieve this with the [custom callback](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/). An untested example:

```
app.post('/auth/register', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-register', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (user) {
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        emailVerification.send(req.user.email, res, req);
        createSendToken(req.user, res);
      });
    // Register failed, flash message is in info
    } else {
      res.status(400).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: yes, that is the only way to do this after a few hours of researching.